# Need help identifying deleteable partitions

Tags: partition, dual-boot, reinstall

I currently have my laptop set up with dual boot windows and linux mint. I'm planning to remove windows completely, so I need to know which partitions I can delete safely to clean up my harddrive, since I have 8 partitions

[image: The partitions, taken from GParted]

1p3 is my windows partition

1p6 is for shared data between windows and linux

1p5 is linux mint

I don't know about the rest. If it helps: I have a Lenovo Thinkpad L380Yoga, the Windows partition is encrypted with bitlocker. If any more info is needed, I'll gladly provide it. Thank you!

For clarity: I want to do a fresh install and need to know if I can safely wipe all partitions. Data is backed up and everything

Answer (score 0):

- 1 Windows boot loader
- 2 EFI
- Unallocated (15 MiB)
- 3 Windows
- 6 Shared between Windows and Mint
- 5 Linux Mint
- 4 Unknown (< 1GiB) but the flags say "diagnostics"
- Unallocated (1 MiB)

Partitions 1, 3, 5 belong to Windows. Partition 2 is the computer's boot data. Partition 5 belongs to Mint. I don't know what partition 4 is, but it could be the `grub` boot partition; it's so small you wouldn't gain anything useful by removing it anyway.

Doesn't look like you have anything spare that can be safely removed.

Comment: I think I worded it poorly. I'm going for a fresh install, and am looking for advice if I can just delete all partitions (except the storage partition) without fucking up my laptop or if there is one or two partitions I shouldn't wipe

Comment: @matthesinator Also don't know what 1p4 is, but it's too small for a preinstallation image or backup partition. I'd mount it and have a look at the files before wiping it.

Comment: @Freddy When I try to mount it, it says `mount : /dev/nvme0n1p4: can't find in /etc/fstab.`

Comment: @matthesinator Try this as root: `mkdir /mnt/whatisthis; mount -t ntfs /dev/nvme0n1p4 /mnt/whatisthis`

Comment: @Freddy that worked, thank you. It contains two folders, one is System Volume Information, which contains a file tracking.log, in which there are LOTS of 0s and a few other characters. The other folder is named Recovery and contains one folder called WindowsRE which contains the files boot.sdi, ReAgent.xml and Winre.wim.

Comment: @matthesinator It's the Windows Recovery Environment (RE), nothing you would want to keep. You may delete it.

Comment: @Freddy alright, thank you!